# Thrift client type cannot be resolved c++

Tags: c++, c++11, thrift, thrift-protocol

I'm hoping to reuse an opened thrift connection to send/recieve multiple messages/responses over the duration of a session.

The client is created in the file

**Client.h**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h>
#include <thrift/transport/TSocket.h>
#include <thrift/transport/TTransportUtils.h>

#include "User.h"
#include <future>

using namespace std;
using namespace apache::thrift;
using namespace apache::thrift::protocol;
using namespace apache::thrift::transport;

Client connect(const std::string &host, int port);

string run_command(Client client, const int32_t op_code, const std::string addr);
```

**Client.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h>
#include <thrift/transport/TSocket.h>
#include <thrift/transport/TTransportUtils.h>

#include "Client.h"
#include <future>

using namespace std;
using namespace apache::thrift;
using namespace apache::thrift::protocol;
using namespace apache::thrift::transport;

Client connect(const std::string &host, int port) {

  std::shared_ptr<TTransport> socket(new TSocket(host, port));  
  std::shared_ptr<TTransport> transport(new TBufferedTransport(socket));
  std::shared_ptr<TProtocol> protocol(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));
  Client client(protocol);
  cout << "CONNECTING";
  transport->open();
  return client;
}

string run_command(Client client, const int32_t op_code, const std::string addr){
  printf("CLIENT\n");
  client.send_run_command(op_code, addr);
  printf("CLIENT SEND_RUN_COMMAND COMPLETE\n");
  string resp;
  client.recv_run_command(resp);
  printf("CLIENT RECV_RUN_COMMAND COMPLETE: %s\n", resp.c_str());
  return resp;
}
```

However, I want to reuse the same client in a different file.

**Shell.cpp**

```
#include "Client.h"
#include <future>

using namespace apache::thrift;
using namespace apache::thrift::protocol;
using namespace apache::thrift::transport;

Client client;


int32_t
taskset_fn(int32_t argc, char** argv) {
    // stuff omitted
    // auto client = connect("127.0.0.1", 9095); -> don't want to recreate client every time
    string output = run_command(client, 6, string(cmd_buf));
    return 0;
}


int lwshell_connect(const std::string &host, int port){
    client = connect("127.0.0.1", 9095);
}
```

Building yields the following error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘ClientT<apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol>::ClientT()’
 Client client;
        ^~~~~~
In file included from [full path omitted]/programs/libuser/librpc/src/Client.h:7:0,
                 from [full path omitted]/programs/libuser
[full path omitted]/programs/libuser/librpc/src/User.h:183:3: note: candidate: ClientT<Protocol_>::ClientT(std::shared_ptr<_Tp>, std::shared_ptr<_Tp>) [with Protocol_ = apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol]
   ClientT(std::shared_ptr< Protocol_> iprot, std::shared_ptr< Protocol_> oprot) {
   ^~~~~~~
[full path omitted]/programs/libuser/librpc/src/User.h:183:3: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
[full path omitted]/programs/libuser/librpc/src/User.h:180:3: note: candidate: ClientT<Protocol_>::ClientT(std::shared_ptr<_Tp>) [with Protocol_ = apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol]
   ClientT(std::shared_ptr< Protocol_> prot) {
   ^~~~~~~
[full path omitted]/programs/libuser/librpc/src/User.h:180:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

**In short, the compiler thinks that `Client client;` is a function call, but I just want a static instance of the client. How can I make a reusable thrift client?**

### Things I've tried

#### 1.

I have tried doing `Client client(std::shared_ptr<TProtocol>);`, which results in

```
: could not convert ‘client’ from ‘Client (*)(std::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol>) {aka ClientT<apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol>
(*)(std::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol>)}’ to ‘Client {aka ClientT<apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol>}’
```

#### 2.

Making the global client a Client*:

**Shell.cpp**

````
Client* client;
...

    Client client_temp = connect("127.0.0.1", 9095);
    client = &client_temp;
    printf("addr: %p\n", (void*) client);
...
    printf("taskset ptr: %p\n", (void*) client);
    string output = run_command(*client, 6, string(cmd_buf));```
````

causes segfault

```
▶ ./ShellUser
CONNECTINGaddr: 0x7fffbfdf2430
$ taskset 1
RECV:taskset 1
, 10
parsing
ARG: taskset
TASKSET
taskset ptr: 0x7fffbfdf2430
[1]    27587 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./ShellUser
```

Comment: In `Shell.cpp`, compiler complains about the global `Client` has no valid arguments to construct. If you don't want to default construct it as an global variable, then use pointer.

Comment: this also didn't work...it causes a segfault :(. I've edited with the results. I'm going to look into modifying my cmake to make it compatible with gdb

Comment: You should create the pointer in the first place instead of using a local instance which would get destructed when out of scope. It seems you don't have enough knowledge of C++. I suggest to read some beginner books in [the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/4123703)

Comment: I see, I didn't consider the notions of lifetimes in C++ that aren't present in C. Guess I'll read up!